# Switch image by variable with Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, replace

I'm writing an image gallery script in which the thumbnail for the currently-viewed image is indicated with a smaller image below the thumbnail. My placeholder is as follows:

```
<img name="indicator0" alt="indicator>
```

with `indicator1`, `indicator2`, etc. following. In my script, which placeholder has the indicator is called by the variable `thumbIndicator`. I'd like to be able to do that like this:

```
document.(thumbIndicator).src = "indicator_image.jpg";
```

but this has not worked. I've also changed my image placeholder to this:

```
<img id="indicator0" alt="indicator">
```

and the script to this:

```
document.getElementByID(thumbIndicator).src = "indicator_image.jpg";
```

but that hasn't worked either.

I have been designing websites for a while now, have a fair amount of experience with PHP/MySQL, but am new to JavaScript. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So is it the case that this can't be done with a variable? I can get it to work by passing a string to getElementId, but I'd like to pass a variable, since there are multiple placeholders. Sounds like it's not possible?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the ID of your placeholder image, (which you might be doing, just not in the code above).

```
<img id="thumbIndicator" alt="alternate text" />
```

Then to get it:

```
document.getElementById("thumbIndicator").src = "newfile.png";
```

In your above code, getElementById had both I and D capitalized, just the I actually is, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a string to `getElementById`:

```
document.getElementByID("thumbIndicator")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="oldsrc" id="thumbindicator" />
```

then

```
document.getElementById('thumbindicator').src = 'newsrc.jpg';
```